# How to ensure component is part of module / nest component in a template?

Tags: angular, components, parent-child, outlet

I'm learning Angular (not AngularJS) and am having trouble getting my template to reference components properly.  Currently it doesn't seem to "see" the referenced component, so I'm either not declaring/importing it in the right place, or I'm using the wrong thing to reference the component from the template, or both.

Either way, I need to know how to get my logo to show up in the layouts from a component.

I'll supply a basic version of the problem:

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { MonkeyModule } from './monkey/monkey.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MonkeyModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <parentComponent></parentComponent>
</body>
</html>
```

monkey.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { parentComponent } from './parent.component';
import { childComponent } from './child.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    parentComponent,
    childComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [parentComponent]
})
export class MonkeyModule { }
```

parent.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { childComponent } from './child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'parentComponent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class parentComponent {
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<div>
This is the Parent!
    <childComponent></childComponent>
</div>
```

child.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'childComponent',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class childComponent {
}
```

child.component.html

```
<div>
    This is the child.
</div>
```

Comment: If you use   ng g c componentname it does all module/component registration.

Comment: Can you show/link a basic example?  Part of the problem is that what you said might be right, but I don't know what that means.

Comment: So apparently "ng g c componentname" refers to a node js command line.
It also did not work: I substituted new component and it still throws the same error.

Comment: I think you need to read up a bit more on Angular.  'ng g c componentName'  is a fundamental part of the Angular CLI.  When we try to do things on your own, it causes us to dig deeper than we want. The Angular CLI already creates components and registers them in the app.module automatically.   It doesn't hurt to lean how to do it without the CLI, but why?  Let the CLI teach us.  Then answer is that the NGModule must import every component and register them.

Comment: Doing that did not work.  It outputs a log of files created and updated so I know I didn't miss anything it didn't do, both the manually created one, and the one created from the CLI both match the pattern exampled in my question.  Both using the selector name and the component name from the generated component resulted in the same error that I received from the manually created component.

Comment: OK try this make a route to get logo component. Then use url to display. Press f12 and select network tab, now press F5 to reload. What do you see?

Comment: I'm not sure on "use url to display", the GetLogo component is using templateURL as is the Index0 component which attempts to load the template, but fails to load the component in the template.

Comment: After experimenting with it more, it looks like I'm having a problem because app-routing is its own module which loads components from the app module, so I'm not sure if it needs to be in both and more specific for each, or I'm misunderstanding the current scopes.

Comment: app.module loads all components.  But app.routing only loads those with a route.  My suggestion to create a route was so you can see what it does by itself.

Comment: I simplified the example to eliminate routing and a second module as possible causes.  The listed example is about simple as I can make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of experimentation, the entire problem seems to boil down to a capital letter in the selector.

The following solves my monkey module problem:
parent.component.html

```
<div>
This is the Parent!
    <child-component></child-component>
</div>
```

child.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class childComponent {
}
```